# Memory copy and memory compare array of array of Single

Tags: delphi, memory, multidimensional-array, copy, compare

In Delphi, I declared a 3x3 matrix table as an array of array of Single, like this:

```
m_Table: array [0..2] of array [0..2] of Single;
```

Now I want to memory compare the content with another table, or memory copy the table content from another table. I know that I can create a nested loop to do that, but I want to do the job without any loop, if possible.

My question is, it is correct to copy or compare the memory like this:

```
CompareMem(m_Table, other.m_Table, 9 * SizeOf(Single));
CopyMemory(m_Table, other.m_Table, 9 * SizeOf(Single));
```

If not, what is the correct way to do that?

And as a subsidiary question, is there a better way to get the length to copy instead of 9 * SizeOf(Single), like e.g. SizeOf(m_Table^)?

Regards

Answer (score 5):

The code in the question works fine. Personally I would say that `Move` is the idiomatic way to copy memory. Further I would use `SizeOf(m_Table)` to obtain the size of the type.

I would point out that your comparison differs from the floating point equality operator. Perhaps that's what you want, but you should be aware of this. For instance zero and minus zero compare equal using floating point comparison but not with memory compare. And NaNs always compare not equal, even with identical bit patterns.

Let me also comment that it would make your code more extendible if you declared a type for these matrices. Without that you won't be able to write functions that accept such objects.

Answer (score 5):

The correct and easiest way may be to define a type:

```
type
  TMatrix3x3 = array [0..2,0..2] of Single;
```

Then you can directly write:

```
var
  v1, v2: TMatrix3x3;
begin
  fillchar(v1,sizeof(v1),0);
  move(v1,v2,sizeof(v1));
  if comparemem(@v1,@v2,sizeof(v1)) then
    writeln('equals');
end;
```

Using `sizeof()` make your code safe and readable.

You may define a wrapper type with methods:

```
{ TMatrix3x3 }

type
  TMatrix3x3 = record
    v: array [0..2,0..2] of Single;
    procedure Zero;
    procedure Copy(var dest: TMatrix3x3);
    procedure Fill(const source: TMatrix3x3);
    function Equals(const other: TMatrix3x3): boolean;
  end;

procedure TMatrix3x3.Copy(var dest: TMatrix3x3);
begin
  move(v,dest,sizeof(v));
end;

function TMatrix3x3.Equals(const other: TMatrix3x3): boolean;
begin
  result := CompareMem(@v,@other.v,sizeof(v));
end;

procedure TMatrix3x3.Fill(const source: TMatrix3x3);
begin
  move(source,v,sizeof(v));
end;

procedure TMatrix3x3.Zero;
begin
  fillchar(v,sizeof(v),0);
end;
```

Including then advanced features like implicit assignment, and operators, if needed.

But don't reinvent the wheel, if you really to work with matrix arithmetic. Use an already existing and fully tested library, which will save you a lot of trouble and debugging time.

Comment: As for existing libraries, I doubt there are good ones that have such types. I know I have rolled all my own routines for such a type.

Comment: Some problems with the enhanced record in the answer. You present  methods that mutate the method subject. That's a problem for records. Leads to semantic errors when you call such a method on a const param. Or even runtime errors if memory is not writeable. Don't have mutating methods on records. Use static class functions that return values. And the equals operator is a little useless without not equals. Further, binary comparison differs from floating point comparison. That is subtle but important.

Comment: Further, your Copy and Fill methods can be removed and in their place the plain old built in `:=` assignment operator used. If you want to set to zero then the best way is to declare a typed constant with that value and use assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You should use standard [TMatrix](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Math.Vectors.TMatrix) type from [System.Math.Vectors](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Math.Vectors) unit, then you can just compare it directly as `if Matrix1 = Matrix2 then` and assign as `Matrix1 := Matrix2`

Comment: You make a big assumption there. That RTL type is for 2D space. But the asker could well be interested in 3D orientation matrices, for instance.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan question is explicitly about 3x3 matrixes

Comment: And the type you refer to is for 2D space. My 3x3 matrices are for 3D space. You don't know whether or not that type is appropriate. You can't tell whether this type is for 2D or 3D.